# Save dynamic generated web page in firefox from bash script

Tags: firefox

I want to save the content of a dynamic generated webpage in a text file for further processing from a bash script under Linux. I`m not interested in the source code; all I want is the output of that page to be saved locally (correspondes to Strg+S in firefox). I tried wget, curl... and all that stuff - but this saved only the static part of the page.
Is there a simple way to save this in a file from command line using firefox or any other browser ?

Comment: What do you mean by static of dynamic part? When you call a PHP document in a server, it gets evaluated and returns HTML (which you could see as "static", but some parts could be dynamically generated). Using the command `curl -o output.txt www.google.com` (or any other website) will save the HTML returned by the server to the `output.txt` file.

Comment: Thank's -but: Using firefox I can save a webpage with "Strg+S enter". How can I do this in a script ?

Comment: Ah! You mean saving the website completely, including images and so? I think it's possible, but hard to do. There are some options doing this using `wget` (by the way, as you need to write questions in English, `Strg` key is known as `Ctrl` key in English).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to download an entire website (let's say, `www.google.com`), you can do it using `wget`:

```
wget --recursive --no-clobber --page-requisites --html-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=unix --domains google.com --no-parent www.google.com
```

According to [this website](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget), you could use these parameters:

- **--recursive** : download the full website
- **--domains google.com** : do not follow (thus download) links outsite of google.com
- **--no-parent** : do not follow links outsite the folder you're calling (this means, if you want to download `www.google.com/firefox`, you won't follow links outsite this `firefox` folder).
- **--page-requisites** : get all elements from the page (CSS, images, scripts, etc).
- **--html-extension** : save the files with `.html` extension.
- **--convert-links** : convert links of type `http://site.domain/folder/doc.html` to `folder/doc.html`, so they'll work locally.
- **--restrict-file-names=unix** : modify filenames (if they are weird) to work fully compatible with UNIX filename conventions (this could be `=windows` for MS Windows filesystems, but I assume you're using an UNIX-compatible operating system).
- **--no-clobber** : do not overwrite existing files (only download what's missing).

Of course, if you want to download another website, you will need to change the `--domains` attribute accordingly. Also, `wget` is not always bundled in all UNIX-compatible operating systems (like Mac OS X, for example), but there are always ways to install it (common GNU/Linux distributions like Ubuntu, Debian, etc. include it by default).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also note that you could use `wget --mirror http://www.google.com` to download the entire site anyway, but the options shown above make this command more powerful if you want to customize your download.